# Create recurring time-based actions in workflow

Tags: workflow, process-builder

How can I create recurring time-based field update (action) in my Work Flow rules?

e.g. for the next 30 days, I want to increment a date field with + 1 Day.

I know this could be done by simply creating a time-based action for EACH day but I am seeking a more cleaner way than inserting 30 actions into my Work Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this way :

1. Create a new date field "Tech Next Date Workflow fire"
2. Create a time based workflow to increment your date with 1 day "0 hour after Tech Next Date Workflow fire"
3. Create a second workflow that update the "Tech Next Date Workflow
       fire" with one day when your date is updated (-> by first workflow)

Then, your time based workflow will update your date, and will be automaticaly restarted one day after. If you want to do it only during X days, you can create an other field to count how many times workflow 1 has been fired, and add a filter.

It seems a bit tricky but it works and should resolve your problem without doing apex.

Comment: I think I understand how this works... Just so we're clear: So I have WORKFLOW1 which when triggered (on certain stage) will update `On_Hold_Days__c` number field by + 1 the current value. I will have a second workflow labelled WORKFLOW2 which triggers when `On_Hold_Days__c` > 0 and when the record is created/updated, this will do two field updates 1 Day after Triggered Date: one to my desired date field `Completion_Date__c` + 1 AND `On_Hold_Days` + 1. On the `On_Hold_Days` field update I assume I need tick "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change". Is this correct?

Comment: Default value for `On_Hold_Days` would be 0.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking more along of the lines of adding another trigger to turn it off when stage changes, but I think setting WORKFLOW 2 to only run when `On_Hold_Days__c` < 30 might be better.

Comment: Indeed it'll be better with this condition.
Just some changes on what you said :
One of your workflow needs to update your `Completion Date`, while the second needs to set the new `Last Triggered Date` with current date, and increment `On_Hold_Days` +1.
The second workflow will trigger every times `On_Hold_Days` is updated.
And the first will trigger "1 day after `Last Triggered Date`"
As you said, set `On_Hold_Days` default value to 0, and `Last Triggered Date` to today date

Comment: I'm a little confused why a `Triggered Date` field would be required to run off the time-base action? Could I not simply use run 1 Day after Trigger Date thats already built into salesforce work flow?

Comment: Because you want to update `Completion Date` every day during 30 days, so you need to know : 1-For how long the workflow is running (`On_Hold_Days`) ; 2-When it has been run for the last time (`Last Triggered Date`). If you only say "Ok, execute this field update 1 day after `Last Triggered Date`" but do not update it, it'll only execute once. That's why you need a second workflow, that update `Last Triggered Date`, and fire again the first (I forgot to say that one of conditions to fire this workflow is `ISCHANGED(Last Triggered Date)`)

Answer (score 1):

Could you create some 'schedulable' apex [(docs here)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) to do the increment and a cron job to run it every day?

Comment: Yes I am aware of cron job apex but my requirements are to use apex only when absolutely nessessary, I would like to use Salesforce applications to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting up 2 workflow rules that will update a custom date field which will mimic recurring workflows like this

Workflow Rule 1 : Update Custom Date field to Today (Immediate Action)

Workflow Rule 2 : Update Custom Date Field to Today (Time-triggered action one day after the first workflow rule). This date will also be a part of the the criteria in the second workflow rule.

The detailed explanation for the same can be found in the below link

[Set up recurring time-based workflow rule](https://force-base.com/2016/11/13/power-of-point-click-series-2-learn-how-to-set-up-recurring-time-based-workflows-in-salesforce/)