# Send notification email after every 4hr

Tags: workflow

I want to send a notification email after every 4hrs after monitoring the record. So I decided to create a last notification field and update it every time the notification email is send. Now I have to check is value of last notification field is changed in workflow then fire a time based workflow after 4hrs. But ischnage method is not accessible with

> created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

and if i change to

> created, and every time it's edited 
>   The time based workflow cannot be added. Is their any other way to achieve it or I need to go for batch class. Please guide

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/65846/2602

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to be "close" to 4 hours, you'd want to use a queueable job which can be chained. At the end of every 4 hours, the job can send and email, then kick off another instance of itself. However, if you have lots of these, you'd have a way to many jobs going at the same time.

A more robust solution would likely be to write these to a temporary object which then loads them into a queueable job every 15 minutes or say 30 minutes to help reduce the number of instances you have going. At the end of each instance, the running job can query to see if there are more records waiting and add them to the queueable before it starts.